# Batch program exiting for no reason without error

Tags: batch-file, compiler-construction

I Am Making A Batch Program For My Other Program "Super Command Promt" (Check it out on pastebin its really good!) And I Noticed It Was A Bit Tricky To Make Plugins For It So I Decided To Start Working On A Simple Compiler To Make It Easier To Make Plugins, But I Cant Seem To Get It To Work! I Open The File Type The Command:

```
compile test.txt test.scmd
```

But It Wont Work It Just Exits Without A Error Instead Of Making The File And Going Going Back To The Prompt Screen

```
Heres the Script:

REM Made By LiamBogur
REM To install copy into notepad and press save as select all files and save it as "SCMDCOMPILER.bat"
REM Feel free to message me or email me at: liamhmccracken@gmail.com (I dont check my email much so try messaging me first)
cls
@echo off
set Version=1.0.0
title Super Command Prompt Plugin Compiler
echo Super Command Prompt Plugin Compiler [Version %Version%]
echo.
:A
set CommandA=
set Command=
set CommandB=
set CommandC=
set /p CommandA=^>
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ("%CommandA%") do set Command=%%i
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ("%CommandA%") do set CommandB=%%i
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ("%CommandA%") do set CommandC=%%i
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Compiler ^| HELP                                   Displays This Message
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Compiler ^| COMPILE [inputfile] [outputfile]       Compiles The Input File Into SCMD Format (eg. input.txt output.scmd)
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Compiler ^| EXIT                                   Exits The Compiler
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Commands ^| COMMAND [command] [commands]           Makes The Command "command" And Makes It Run "commands"
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Commands ^| RUN [commands]                         Run Some Commands In Batch 
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Commands ^| COMMENT [comment]                      Adds A Comment To Your File
if /I %Command%==HELP echo Commands ^| HELP [message]                         Adds That Message To PHELP (eg."HELP Restart    Restarts The Computer")
if /I %Command%==EXIT exit
if /I %Command%==COMPILE goto B
goto A
:B
echo Decoding %CommandB%.
for /f "delims=*" %%i in (%CommandB%) do (
set WordN=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%u in ("%%i") do (
set /A WordN+=1
if %WordN%==1 (
set CCommand=0
if /I %%u==COMMAND (
set CCommand=1
set LineO=if ^%A^%==2 if /I ^%Command^%==
)
if /I %%u==RUN (
set CCommand=2
set LineO=call
)
if /I %%u==COMMENT (
set CCommand=3
set LineO=rem
)
if /I %%u==HELP (
set CCommand=4
set LineO=if ^%A^%==2 if /I ^%Command^%==PHELP echo %CommandC:~0,-5% ^^^|
)
) else (
if CCommand==1 (
set LineO=%LineO%%%u
) else (
set LineO=%LineO% %%u
)
)
echo %LineO%>>C:\Users\Public\Temp.txt
)
mv C:\Users\Public\Temp.txt %CommandC%
goto A
```

I really need help with this one!

Edit 1:
Heres the code for test.txt:

```
COMMENT Lol this is cool
COMMAND test Lol 123 456
HELP Oh No!
```

And Heres What Its Meant To Look Like Compiled

```
REM Lol this is cool
if %A%==2 if /I %Command%==test Lol 123 456
if %A%==2 if /I %Command%==PHELP echo TEST ^| Oh No!
```

Comment: Why do you capitalise every single word?? Anyway, you should run your batch file by opening a command prompt window and typing its path rather than double-clicking it, so you can see any error messages...

Comment: Start by commenting out `@echo off`. Disabling echo will mean that you won't see what commands are being executed when the script runs.

Comment: If you solved your question, post the solution, then mark it as the answer as soon as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that for some reason, for my specific program, nested for loops were being a bit buggy. They would just behave randomly and didn't really work, so I created a function, put my second for loop in there, and just had the first loop call the function. Then, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Nested loops work just fine in batch. Note: you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) for using variables that you created/changed within the same code block/loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error message I see after ensuring that echo is on is:

```
echo was unexpected at this time.
```

This is not entirely enlightening, but it does suggest a syntax error (though not with echo—probably with what comes before it).

### Encapsulate String Variables

The fundamental problem I see with what you're doing is that you're doing string comparisons with variables that may be empty, and you're not enclosing them inside quotes. This becomes a syntax error, because then cmd runs a command that looks like

```
if /I ==HELP echo Commands ^| HELP [message]
```

cmd *is not smart* about variables. It's doing a straightforward substitution wherever the variable is referenced.

The typical method for constructing non-fragile (*robust* is an overstatement when applied to anything regarding cmd) is to enclose both LHS and RHS values within quotes so that empty values result in syntactically legal statements.

```
if /I "%Command%"=="HELP" echo Commands ^| HELP [message]
```

This way, when the substitution takes place (for the last line of input) in which `Command` is empty, the command executed looks like this

```
if /I ""=="HELP" echo Commands ^| HELP [message]
```

which is syntactically legal.

### Use /B with Exit

You probably want to use `EXIT /B` rather than just `EXIT`, because `EXIT` by itself will end the calling cmd process, which, in testing, is usually your cmd window. Most people don't want this to happen. `EXIT /B` will end the script without ending the shell process.

Comment: Thanks! But I Fixed It Now! I Re-coded The Compiling Part And Also Figured Out That Batch Doesnt Really Like Nested Loops So I Created A Function And The Loop Just Calls The Function So Its Technically Not Inside Another Loop!

Comment: I feel pity for your `SHIFT` key.

Comment: Needed for loops "work" just as well as any other programming construct in batch. Nested goto loops are almost as cumbersome as in any other language.